# FileMover 24hrs - Python

Tags: python, datetime, shutil

so I am supposed to move files(.txt)that are new and that have also been edited within a 24hour time frame. Files with the extension .txt should go from folder A to B. My code works, however, it is moving one single file at a time after every time I press F5 to run the program. Would someone please help me move all files by clicking just once?

Thanks

```
import os
import datetime
import shutil

source = ("/Users/SD/Desktop/A")
destination = ("/Users/SD/Desktop/B")
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
oldFile = currentTime - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
for files in os.listdir(source):
    if files.endswith('.txt'):
        path = os.path.join(source, files)
        st = os.stat(path)
        mTime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mTime)

        if mTime > oldFile:
            print('{} ~ last modified {}'.format(path, mTime))

fileSource = os.path.join(source, files)
fileDestination = os.path.join(destination, files)
shutil.move(fileSource, fileDestination)
print("\tMoved {} to {}.\n".format(files, destination))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is off i think in your code, you move the file after the `for`-loop. This results in only the last file of the `for`-loop being moved. Move the last bit of code inside the loop, and inside the last `if`-statement specifically, to move any file that matches your criteria.

Furthermore your time testing really confuses me, and i doubt it even does what you think it does. I've replaced it with a (to me) clearer testing...

```
import os
import datetime
import shutil

source = ("/Users/../Desktop/A")
destination = ("/Users/../Desktop/B")
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
for files in os.listdir(source):
    if files.endswith('.txt'):
        path = os.path.join(source, files)
        st = os.stat(path)
        #---New Time Test setup---#
        tDelta = currentTime - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
        maxDelta = 24*3600
        if tDelta.total_seconds() < maxDelta:
            print('{} ~ last modified {}'.format(path, tDelta))
            fileSource = os.path.join(source, files)
            fileDestination = os.path.join(destination, files)
            shutil.move(fileSource, fileDestination)
            print("\tMoved {} to {}.\n".format(files, destination))
```

Files before:

```
..\Desktop\A\
  -text_a.txt
  -text_b.txt
..\Desktop\B\
  ~Empty~
```

Files after:

```
..\Desktop\A\
  ~Empty~
..\Desktop\B\
  -text_a.txt
  -text_b.txt
```

PS: I assume there is a little error in your code and `oldFile` should be `dayOld` or vice versa. You should edit this...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. So I changed up everything you mentioned above but still nothing :/. Its actually giving me more errors for unnecessary indentations.

Comment: Whut? Define unnecessary? Where does it fail? Can you post the error?

Comment: I checked it: i got an error on `st.st_mTime` which apparently should be `st.st_mtime` (no capital T, which i'll change in the answer too). Other than that it works for me. Double check the indentation, if necessary reindent from scratch...

Comment: Hey mate, okay this is so strange but it tells me......"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 "/Users/SD/Desktop/Tech Academy /TechAcademyProjects/Python/File_Mover_Drills/file_mover.py"

Process finished with exit code 0
"....... However, it doesn't move the file. Ive been trying different variations.

Comment: Ok, I read up on datetime, as it wasn't as up to par in my head... Reading back the code i really can't follow what you are trying with the `timedelta` object and i doubt it even does what you(we...) think it does. I've edited the code in the answer once more and it again works on my system, but now at least i'm sure the comparison in the if statement is valid and actually testing the time limit correctly. I played around with the comparison value, and have seen it move files that were valid, and leave behind invalid files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Idk what happened but I got both codes you provided to work now.